# Why is the resource theory approach used in quantum information processing?

Tags: computational-models, resource-theories

What are the advantages and applications of using the resource theory approach in QIP ? What specific problems can be solved using in particular this approach ?

Comment: Hi @C. Sophie!  Welcome to QCSE!  Can you edit the question to try to summarize what your understanding of the "resource theory approach" to quantum information processing is?